# Spring Security Custom UserDetailsService to use User Service/Dao

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using a custom UserDetailsService to authenticate users. This uses a PersonDao/Service object that is autowired. To autowire this object, I had to include reference to datasource, sessionfactory and annotation driven in Spring-security-context.xml. All these lines are exactly replicated in app-servlet.xml. So I was wondering if there is anyway to have theses lines in only one place and not to copy it at both the places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app-servlet (Spring MVC) context is a child of the root WebApplicationContext and has access to all of the beans in the parent.

If your parent context includes spring-security-context (for example)

```
<import resource="spring-security-context.xml"/>
```

then app-servlet will have access to those beans.

See [What's a smart way to organize classes in Spring 3 for component-scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959749/whats-a-smart-way-to-organize-classes-in-spring-3-for-component-scan/6960626#6960626) for info on how to not duplicate beans when `<component-scan>`ing.