# How do you share Spring beans between different Spring contexts?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, blazeds

We have an application which uses Spring BlazeDS integration. So far we have just been using Spring and Flex, and it is working fine. We now have a requirement to add some Spring MVC controllers as well. The Spring BlazeDS documentation states that the way to do this is to declare two sperate contexts in the **web.xml**, as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my question: There are Spring beans which are required to be used within both contexts - the **spring-mvc** one and the **flex** one. How can one do this - how can one declare a bean (either in xml or by component scanning) in one context and allow it to be shared with beans declared in the other context?
Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Create a parent context by using [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create).   The `DispatcherServlet` contexts will automatically become children of that context.

Create your shared beans in the parent context and refer to them in beans in the child contexts.

If you are using `<component-scan>` make sure you don't accidentally scan classes into multiple contexts.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959749/whats-a-smart-way-to-organize-classes-in-spring-3-for-component-scan/6960626#6960626).

Comment: "accidentally scan classes into multiple context is a key point" here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/YOUR_APP_CONTEXT.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Both beans defined via scanning and direct definitions will be available for your BlazeDS and SpringMVC endpoints.