# Use Apache cxf with spring mvc in a single application with shared services

Tags: spring, apache, hibernate, model-view-controller, cxf

I'm currently working a project which based on spring MVC, it's just a standard project using spring MVC template. so I have web.xml and servlet-context.xml.

I'm working on adding Apache cxf web services into this project, and meet some problems on sharing services with existing Spring MVC.

My initial approach was trying to get web services working, so here is my web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/jaxwsServlet/jaxwsServlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>




    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Process web service requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jaxws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jaxws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/industryAspectWS</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my jaxwsServlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
        classpath:spring-jax-ws-core.xsd
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
        classpath:spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
>   
    <wss:binding url="/industryAspectWS">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#industryAspectWS"/>
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <!-- Web service methods -->
    <bean id="industryAspectWS" class="com.example.ws.IndustryAspectWS"></bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <beans:import resource="../HibernateTransaction.xml" />

    <beans:import resource="../JaxbMarshaller.xml" />

</beans>
```

I copied the ***context:component-scan beans:import*** sections from servlet-context.xml

This configuration works okay since I was able to boot up the server, and call Web services and also access servlet and jsp. **However, I notice that since I quoted the hibernateTransaction.xml in both context xml files, there are two session factories.**

I want to share all services (such as hibernate) between Apache cxf and Spring MVC controllers, so I tried to put settings in root-context.xml, it didn't work. I also tried to search this online, but didn't find any complete examples on shared services. Is it possible that we can put a setting to share services among the two?

=================================================

I had experimented some settings after I post this, and figured that if I put the lines of

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

and

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerExample" />
```

in both servlet-context.xml and jaxwsServlet-context.xml, it will work just fine. all other settings can stay in the shared root-context.xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WSSpringServlet` is not CXF.  It is Metro.  I would recommend using CXF.   In that case you will have a `CXFServlet` but then you would set up CXF in your main Spring context (the one created by `ContextLoaderListener`.

It would work as follows: your main context would have all of the shared beans including CXF.   Your Servlet context would have just your controllers.  Since the servlet context is a child of the main context your controllers would also have access to everything in the main context.

See the [Embedding CXF inside of Spring page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html), the [CXF Servlet Transport Page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html), and [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339174/how-do-you-share-spring-beans-between-different-spring-contexts/10342499#10342499) about sharing beans between servlet context and main context.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30758664/2615824:

Two dispatchers (Spring MVC REST Controller and CXF JAX-WS) with one Spring Context, Java Config (no xml stuff...) example:

WebApplicationInitializer:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(MyServiceConfig.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webContext.setParent(rootContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic restDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("REST dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webContext));
    restDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    restDispatcher.addMapping("/api/*");

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic cxfDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("CXF dispatcher", CXFServlet.class);
    cxfDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    cxfDispatcher.addMapping("/services/*");
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.root.package")
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"})
@PropertySource("classpath:app-env.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Bus cxfBus;

    @Autowired
    private CxfEndpointImpl cxfEndpoint;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint cxfService() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, cxfEndpoint);
        endpoint.setAddress("/CxfEndpointImpl");
        endpoint.setWsdlLocation("classpath:CxfService/CxfService-v1.0.wsdl");
        endpoint.publish();
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Sample CXF Endpoint (WSDL first):

```
@Component
@WebService(
        endpointInterface = ".....v1_0.CxfServicePort",
        targetNamespace = "http://..../service/CxfService/v1_0",
        serviceName = "CxfService",
        portName = "CxfServicePort",
        wsdlLocation = "classpath:CxfService/CxfService-v1.0.wsdl")
@MTOM(enabled = true)
@SchemaValidation(type = SchemaValidationType.BOTH) 
@InInterceptors(classes = NoBinaryContentLoggingInInterceptor.class)
@OutInterceptors(classes = NoBinaryContentLoggingOutInterceptor.class)
@EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.callback-handler", ref = "cxfEndpointSecurityHandler")
public class CxfEndpointImpl implements CxfServicePort {

    //...

}
```

Sample REST Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/system", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RestController {

    //...
}
```

CXF Endpoint deployment address:

```
ip:port/tomcat-context/services/CxfEndpointImpl?wsdl
```

Spring REST Controller deployment address:

```
ip:port/tomcat-context/api/system
```