# Migration to Spring project from JSP/Servlet/Portlets(Jetspeed) - application design

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I am in process of migrating existing jsp/servlet/portlet(jetspeed) based application to spring. Me and my colleague are the only developers to design, code, deploy and maintain applications (The reason i listed duties is not to show off but rather to explain my responsibility and impact of my actions). Wanted to be wary of my initial application design & architecture before it is too late to realize. The existing web application is already being used worldwide. I have encountered few questions while designing new application.

1) Number of webapps to squeeze the application into: Currently, i have 5 webapps. If required, all of these can be clubbed into one webapp that helps to avoid additional coding to share data between them upon migrating to spring. However, do not want to compromise on the scalability & maintenance. For an instance, do not want to deploy whole war file for a single class change. My question: What are the factors that need to be considered while designing and chosing one vs more than one webapps?

2) Data sharing between webapps: In case of having more than one webapp, data need to be shared. I am thinking of the solution that is less abstract. I am comparatively new to spring and currently share data between webapps by filters & request objects between two contexts. Was able to find couple of posts like (
[How do you share Spring beans between different Spring contexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339174/how-do-you-share-spring-beans-between-different-spring-contexts)) but do not want to end up in too much of abstraction until i am aware of spring. But, again i realize that comparatively its difficult to implement changes at the later stages of project. My Question: Any other ways of sharing data between different spring contexts with less abstraction?

3) Version of spring to use. Sure the latest due to its features but wanted to chose the one that has more community support. I do not see in near future that i need to use all the advanced features of spring in latest releases.

4) View: I am planning to use JSTL as a presentation layer by converting existing JSP's  as i have worked on it a bit and are straight(less abstraction). My Question: Any other technology other than JSTL like JSF and your suggestions for JSTL.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question 2. If you have spring beans to share between different apps. I would consider defining a separate module for it. For example if you have webapp1, webapp2 that use commons beans for validating some business rules. You can create a module called validation-manager which will be packaged as a jar file and included as a dependency for both webapp1 and webapp2.

To have both webapp1 and webapp2 have access to those common beans included in the jar, you can configure those beans like the following in your application context:

validation-manager application context config

```
<!-- beans definitions shared between webapp1 and webapp2 -->
<bean id="userValidation" class="com.example.UserValidation" />
<bean id="orderValidation" class="com.example.OrderValidation" />
```

webapp1 config

```
<!-- import beans definitions for validation-manager -->
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-validation-manager.xml" />

<!-- beans definitions specific to webapp1 -->
```

webapp2 config

```
<!-- import beans definitions for validation-manager -->
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-validation-manager.xml" />

<!-- beans definitions specific to webapp2 -->
```

The idea is to modularize your code as much possible to be able to reuse common functionalities in different webapps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this spring configuration similar to the non-spring application of placing the jar files in tomcat/shared folder and using the classes in different webapps. example: shared/mydao.jar ? Secondly, where does the validation-manager.xml & validation-beans.jar reside, in tomcat/shared ? Thirdly, what should be the classpath set to for webapp1 & webapp2 to find the validation-manager.xml? Thanks for your time.

Comment: In tomcat your application jar files will reside in your <app_name>/WEB-INF/lib directory. So for webapp1, your shared jar will be deployed under <tomcat_install>/webapps/webapp1/WEB-INF/lib/validation-manager.jar and webapp2 will be the same <tomcat_install>/webapps/webapp2/WEB-INF/lib/validation-manager.jar. Tomcat documentation discouraged the deployment of application jar to <tomcat_install>/lib directory because jar files under this directory are both visible to tomcat internal classes as well as application specific classes. validation-manager.xml will be packaged at the root of the jar

Comment: One question I have for you. Are you planning to use maven or ant for your projects? I strongly recommend using maven.

Comment: I am using ant. Will switch to maven in future. I was waiting to execute your suggested approach to see if i come up with any issues but it will take me some more time. I am accepting your answer as 2nd point was the primary one of all 4 points i asked. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck with the project and I highly recommend switching to maven early in the process rather than late.

Answer (score 0):

here's an attempt to answer your questions;

1. separate webapps do make it easier to maintain and 'silo' the effect of changes as long as you've got good version control and release management cycles.  my suggestion is to allow for a transitional migration by migrating one app at a time to a 'Spring-compliant' style rather than go for a 'big bang' approach.
2. in terms of data-sharing, you'll need to think about a couple of things and whether or not you're treating each individual web app as 'service' (capable of sharing the information with not just the other web apps but future applications) or as a separate known/coupled web app.  if you're going for the former, there's a wide variety of options from RESTful services and messaging services. if you're going for the latter, then you're looking at slightly more coupled data sharing approaches.  in any event, you may want to make yourself familiar with `Spring Integration` as a means of exchanging messages/data between applications as it abstracts away from the consuming application and the messaging conduit.  have a look at [Spring Integration documents](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) for a starter on it along with [EAI patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/) for the theory.
3. go with the latest; there's a little bit of a transition bump from 3.1 to 3.2 but there's some really neat Spring Web/MVC test tools included in 3.2 that will really help with your development.  (have a look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework))
4. JSTL and JSF have different interaction patterns so if you're using JSP & JSTL in the current apps, Spring MVC supports it very well and has a lot of resources available.  (nothing against JSF, just why introduce additional complexity)